# How do i edit/delete data from the frontend in Django with Elasticsearch?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-forms, edit

I would like to retrieve data from my backend (postgresql) to the frontend so i can edit/delete it.

Note: My project is using django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf

I have implemented this in views.py:

```
def update(request, id):
    resp = Response.objects.get(pk = id)
    resp.response = request.POST.get('Response')
    resp.save()
    return render(request, 'app/update', {
    })
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'update/(\d+)/$', views.update, name="update")
```

How would i display it in my forms?

update.html:

```
<table class="dataTable">

{% for field in qform.visible_fields %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ field.label_tag }}*</th>
        <td>{{ field }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
    <tr>
        <th>{{ rform.Response.label_tag }}*</th>
        <td>{{ rform.Response }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ rform.Topic.label_tag }}*</th>
        <td>{{ rform.Topic }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ rform.Client.label_tag }}*</th>
        <td>{{ rform.Client }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ rform.Planit_location.label_tag }}*</th>
        <td>{{ rform.Planit_location }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ rform.Date_added.label_tag }}</th>
        <td>{{ rform.Date_added }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>{{ rform.Document.label_tag }}</th>
        <td>{{ rform.Document }}</td>
    </tr>
```

Also I am getting an Assertion error "No exception message supplied" when i try to access the url .../update

EDIT
StackTrace:

```
Internal Server Error: /update/3/
django_1         | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
django_1         |     response = get_response(request)
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
django_1         |     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
django_1         |     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
django_1         |   File "/app/app/views.py", line 358, in update
django_1         |     "rform": resp,
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
django_1         |     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string
django_1         |     template = get_template(template_name, using=using)
django_1         |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template
django_1         |     raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)
django_1         | django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: app/update/
```

Comment: As the traceback shows, this doesn't have anything to do with editing on the frontend, but with the django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf package. Have you configured that correctly?

Comment: It has been working as we would like it to so far. Is there something i need to add to it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i changed the stacktrace. The URL i was using initially was wrong e.g. .../update. Should have been .../update/<id>. The error is now templatenotexist. Currently my template is named update.html. Should it be something else?

Comment: If your template is called "update.html", you should use "app/update.html" in your render call, not "app/update".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url path should be:

```
url(r'update/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.update, name="update")
```

Also, you need to return something from your update method:

```
   return render(request, 'update_add.html', { 'rform': resp })
```

Comment: Ok but that doesn't solve the issue with the assertion error. Do i have to implement try catch in my views.py?

Comment: can put your full stacktrace in your question please?

Comment: added the stacktrace

Comment: you are using `django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf`? you did not include anything regarding that in the original question

Comment: Didn't know i had to. I'll add it in the question

Comment: Well, I don't have any idea in `django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf`. Maybe its a configuration issue.

Comment: I changed the stacktrace, was accessing just .../upload instead of .../upload/<id>. Using .../upload/3 as an example, i get the templatenotfound error. Am i suppose to name my html something else instead of upload.html?

Comment: if you are using `update_add.html` as template name for rendering data, then you should use it. if its in `abc` folder of the `TEMPLATE_DIR`, then please use `abc/update_add.html`

Comment: return render(request, 'app/update/', {"rform": resp,})

This is what i am using right now but i still get the error

Comment: If you want to redirect, then use `return redirect('/app/update/')` if its a valid url path. if you want to render a template then use `return render(request, 'template_name.html', {rform: resp})`. Hope it helps

Comment: omg i am an idiot. Didn't notice i was missing the .html bit. Thanks

Comment: Ruddra, i have managed to get a selected PK to display on my edit page. But the issue now is that i cannot make any changes to it, it is just displaying the information with a Submit button at the buttom

Comment: okay, for that you need to use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/). It would be great if you could give it a try, and if something goes south, then post a new question. thanks